# Scripts to change values across different record types - Netsuite Suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am currently watching a lot of tutorials and doing a lot of research on SuiteScript 2.0

But before I get into this I want to ask a fundamental question.

Can I edit a field on a particular record type with a script that runs on a different record type.

For example

I have a custom field on my Inventory Item Page. (Item Record)

I want to run a script from Goods Receipt Note (Transaction Record)

So that when the goods receipt note is saved it amends a custom field on the item page.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function beforeSubmit(context) {

    var new_rec = context.newRecord;

    var item_count = new_rec.getLineCount({
        sublistId: "item"
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < item_count; i++) {

        var item_id = new_rec.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'item',
            line: i
        });

        var avgCost = search.lookupFields({
            type: "inventoryitem",
            id: item_id,
            columns: ['averagecost']
        }).averagecost;

        var updateAvgCost = record.submitFields({
            type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
            id: item_id,
            values: {
                custitem1: Number(avgCost).toFixed(2)
            }
        });
      }
```

Comment: You can refer the above code

Comment: thank you so much, that's incredible, and unexpected, I really appreciate the help. Thank you. I will utilise this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Generally not a problem as long as the role the script is being run under has write access to the item.

The main thing is transactions can tend to have many lines and if you are updating your items one-by-one you can run into script governance issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know. 

It just occurred to me in everything I’ve discovered so far that I’ve not seen any examples of this and I didn’t want to spend the next few weeks living and breathing code only to find out it’s not actually possible. Essentially I want to identify the item on the GRN, calculate its location average cost and put it into a custom field on the item page. 

I appreciate your advice RE permissions and transaction line quantities. I will persevere! Cheers.